# file.write return invalid syntax only for one element

Tags: python-2.7, file, logging, syntax, python-3.8

here is something I can't figure out.
I'm trying to get different things from a file (games.log) and store them into another.

But i'm getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" here : `file2.write(f"USER_{index}\n")`

```
def get_users():
    # Open game log file
    file = open('games.log', 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()

    # open/create user file to store data
    file2 = open('users.log', 'w')
    index = 0
    for line in lines:
        name = ''
        guid = ''
        ip = ''
        player = ''
        if 'spawned' in line:
            line = remove_colorcode(line)
            # Get IP
            ip = get_ip(line)

            # Get player number
            player = line[line.find('Player') + 7: line.find('spawned')]
            player.strip(' ')

            # Get name
            name = get_name(line)
            # Get guid
            guid = get_guid(line)

            # Write to file
            file2.write(f"USER_{index}\n")
            file2.write(f"IP:{ip}\n")
            file2.write(f"Name: {name}\n")
            file2.write(f"ja_guid:{guid}\n\n")

            index += 1

    file.close()
    file2.close()
```

file2.write(f"USER_{index}\n") is invalid syntax. But I can't figure why ?

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please don't use [tag:parsing] for syntax errors in particular languages. This tag is for questions about writing parsers.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mistake. I won't repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted string literals (`f"..."`) are a feature of Python 3. (And only since Python 3.6.) Python 2 doesn't have them.

If you want to use them, use Python 3. That's a good plan in any case.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Indeed I have tried with python-2.7. But now i'am getting `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` on python-3.8.5.

Comment: @MaëlIngold: on which line? It works just fine for me on python-3.8.5

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid. But I'am using python-3.8 console, and it doesn't tel me which line is in cause.

Comment: It's the line 1 in cause.

Which is `from colorremover import remove_colorcode`
the file colorremover.py is next to my current script in the same folder. I'am confused what is the problem here.

Comment: @maël: And you can see all your files. I can see nothing :-) But presumably there is some error in colorremover.py. Check it's syntax. (`python3 colorremover.py`, if your python3.8.5 is called `python3`. That will tell you where and what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Forgive my noobish :-)
https://imgur.com/a/bNq3h1P

This is the content of colorremover.py. I lack to see where is error here. :-/

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. You'll have to try parsing your various files with python, as I suggested, until you find one with an error. It's possible that copy-and-paste isn't working properly on your console; using files is easier and more reliable.